TIA beta factor
I read in Wikipedia the circuit and operation of the transimpedance amplifier.

I elaborated on this website the steps to find the transfer function.


I do not understand how to calculate the feedback factor (beta).


\$\beta\$ is just the ratio between a signal at the output node and the feedback voltage produced at the summing node (the inverting input of the op-amp) due to that signal:
$$\beta=\frac{V_i}{V_o}$$
From the voltage divider rule this is:
$$\beta = \frac{Z_i}{Z_i+Z_f}$$
From there it's just algebraic manipulation to get the form used in your text:
$$\beta = \frac{1/sC_i}{1/sC_i + (R_f/sC_f)/(R_f+1/sC_f)}$$
$$\beta = \frac{1}{1 + sC_i(R_f/sC_f)/(R_f+1/sC_f)}$$
$$\beta = \frac{1}{1 + sC_i R_f/(sR_fC_f+1)}$$
$$\beta = \frac{1+sR_fC_f}{1 + sR_fC_f + sC_i R_f}$$
$$\beta = \frac{1+sR_fC_f}{1 + sR_f(C_f + C_i)}$$
